# 3ds import menu

Tags: import

I need to change Size Constraint option for 3ds import. Could somebody navigate me to this menu ?

Somebody posted this picture and I cannot seem to find it anywhere.

[image]

Comment: Operator menu. File > import > 3ds, then bottom left below your bookmarks and such...

Comment: Yes, in case it is not clear it shows up after you go to *File > Import* in the file manager itself